# Using DynamoDb and DocClient, is it possible to use an updateExpression that relies on two attributes and a division?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

First thing's first, it seems updateExpression only supports + or - with an N value.

Let's say we have a table `User`, and user has: `totalReviews`, `totalReviewValues`, and `averageRating`. AverageRating = totalReviewValues / totalReviews.

e.g.:

```
{ 
  userID: 'someID',
  totalReviewValues: 9,
  totalReviews: 2,
  averageRating: 4.5
```

I would like to do some update expression:

```
aws dynamodb update-item \
    --table-name User \
    --key '{"id":{"S": userID }}' \
    --update-expression "SET averageRating = totalReviewValues / totalReviews" \
    --return-values ALL_NEW
```

now I understand this is not possible, but is there a recommended approach to accomplish this without using a GET/Update pattern? I need the averageRating so that I can sort by it.

I do have one approach, where I can add a stream to User, and whenever there is an UPDATE and `totalReviews` and `totalReviewValues` are different, I can then update the averageRating?

Comment: It's unclear to me what information you have when you're trying to store the new value of `averageRating`.  At this point, what info do you have about the `User` entity?

Comment: I tried to simplify the question, but in reality this is a transaction, where all I have is `averageRating`. The totalReviewValues and totalReviews is not available without a GET, or without using a trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to do what you are asking with DynamoDB.

DynamoDB only supports per-item operations. Even when you perform a transaction, using the new transactions API, you are still operating on each item individually.

Said differently, DynamoDB does not support aggregations. If you want to compute say, the sum of multiple items, you would need to do that in your application.